# Sample text to collect all possible English biphones for Text-To-Speech

Tags: speech-synthesis

Since the list of phonemes in English is fixed, it should be possible to come up with a sample text(s) to collect all possible biphones for text-to-speech synthesis.

Does anyone have a sample text for this purpose?

Comment: The question is not fully determined, as the pronunciation of biphones is a matter of dialect. I think You are looking for a text that will cover all biphones in all dialects, which is a little more to ask.

Comment: technically, even a list of all biphones of every language very limited since the total number of IPA signs are sorted of limited to a handful, no?

Comment: Covering all the biphones is easy. The hard part in text to speech is getting all the different ways people pronounce each phone.

Comment: if data size is large enough, wouldn't it be a normalization problem to get the most representative sound file that suits a certain biphone?

Answer (score 1):

The "Harvard sentences" corpus is a classic:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_sentences